# Increase conventional RAM in Wndows

Tags: basic, qbasic

I have a program that requires 512KB of conventional RAM but my cmd.exe only reports 500KB. My question is how do I increase RAM to the program. Thanks.

Comment: Is there some reason you have to use QBASIC?

Comment: The program i am using is in qbasic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your best bet is to use a more modern programming language, but if you're constrained to QBASIC for whatever reason, you might give QB64 a try: https://www.qb64.org/

Answer (score 1):

I managed to free some conventional ram by specifying:

```
rem config.nt file contents:
emm=ram
dos=high,umb
devicehigh=%SystemRoot%\system32\himem.sys
devicehigh=%SystemRoot%\system32\ansi.sys
files=255
```

Answer (score 1):

After freeing up some RAM in Windows, using MEM declares the following:

```
655360 bytes total conventional memory
655360 bytes available to MS-DOS
626224 largest executable program size

1048576 bytes total contiguous extended memory 
     0 bytes available contiguous extended memory 
 941056 bytes available XMS memory 
     MS-DOS resident in High Memory Area
```

But what I cannot figure out is why the available contiguous extended memory is always 0?